# Вектор указателей на функции с любым типом принимаемых и возвращаемых данных

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Имеется класс `Menu`. В методе `start` выполняются какие-то действия, в результате чего должна выполниться какая-либо заранее неизвестная функция из контейнера функций `functionPointers`. Добавлять функции в контейнер должен метод `add`. Пример добавляемой функции - `GenericFunction`

Для решения этой задачи я сделал контейнер на функции типа <void(void)> и, как показано далее в коде, к примеру через лямбда-функцию я могу передать любой алгоритм с любыми параметрами.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template <typename T> T GenericFunction(T arg) {
  T a = arg * 2;
  std::cout << a;
  return a;
}

class Menu {
private:
  std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> functionPointers;

public:
  void add(void (*foo)()) {
    functionPointers.push_back(foo);
    return;
  }
  void start() {
    //Какие-то действия
    functionPointers[0]();
    return;
  }
};

int main() {
  Menu mn;
  mn.add([]() { GenericFunction(5); });
  mn.start();
  return 0;
//Выводит 10
}
```

Но так как хранилище у меня для функций <void(void)>, я не могу в него передавать аргументы извне, если только это не глобальная переменная:

```
int main() {
  Menu mn;
  int a=4;
  mn.add([a]() { GenericFunction(a); });
  mn.start();
  return 0;
//При компиляции выводит ошибку
```

Возможно есть какие либо другие способы передать и хранить нужную функцию с нужными мне аргументами. Любым подсказкам буду рад.

Comment: C++ является языком со статической типизацией, соответственно типы функций, их параметров и возвращаемых значений должны быть известны во время компиляции и хранить или, тем более, выполнять, заранее неизвестные функции не получится.

Comment: В `add`, измени тип параметра на `std::function<void(void)>`, тогда сможешь передавать лямбда с захватом переменных. Только замени `push_back`, на `emplace_back`, чтобы перемешать параметр, а не копировать его.

Comment: Спасибо, @evo, всё заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо в функции `add`, заменить тип параметра на

```
std::function<void(void)>
```

Так же изменить `push_back` на `emplace_back`, чтобы избежать лишнего копирования объекта.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template <typename T> T GenericFunction(T arg) {
  T a = arg * 2;
  std::cout << a;
  return a;
}

class Menu {
private:
  std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> functionPointers;

public:
  void add(std::function<void(void)> foo) {
    functionPointers.emplace_back(foo);
    return;
  }
  void start() {
    //Какие-то действия
    functionPointers[0]();
    return;
  }
};

int main() {
  Menu mn;
  int a { 5 };
  mn.add([a]() { GenericFunction(a); });
  mn.start();
  return 0;
  //Выводит 10
}
```

P.S. Ещё лучше завести алиас типа, чтобы не писать каждый раз `std::function<void(void)>`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template <typename T> T GenericFunction(T arg) {
  T a = arg * 2;
  std::cout << a;
  return a;
}

class Menu {
public:
  using function_type = std::function<void(void)>;
private:
  std::vector<function_type> functionPointers;

public:
  void add(function_type foo) {
    functionPointers.emplace_back(foo);
    return;
  }
  void start() {
    //Какие-то действия
    functionPointers[0]();
    return;
  }
};

int main() {
  Menu mn;
  int a { 5 };
  mn.add([a]() { GenericFunction(a); });
  mn.start();
  return 0;
  //Выводит 10
}
```